# For a group ring, finding if a subset is an ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups, ideals, group-rings

For the ring $R=SG$, the group ring of a finite group G over an integral domain S, and a subset $I=(g-1|g \in G)$, is this subset an ideal? Is it prime? How about maximal?

Comment: The notation seems to denote the ideal generated by the elements $g-1$ for $g\in G$, so it is an ideal by definition. Note that the *set* $\{g-1:g\in G\}$ is generally not closed under addition.

Answer (score 2):

See [augmentation ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmentation_ideal). Obviously, augmentation map $\varepsilon$ is an epimorphism $R\to S$. Then $I=\ker(\epsilon)$ and $R/I\cong S$. So if $G$ commutative, then $I$ is a prime ideal of a commutative ring $R$. If $G$ nonabelian, then $R$ noncommutative and I don't know, what is the name for such ideals. From this clear, that $I$ maximal iff $S$ is a field (since $R/I\cong\varepsilon(R)=S$).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I see now. And thanks for the link!